# Is there a way to resolve a 'bad instruction temporary' error?

Tags: armv7

I am trying to get this ARM code to work and I am getting a 'bad instruction temporary', which I have checked with online sources and should be positioned correctly.

I did another piece of code and it had similar syntax to this one, but there were no errors. That one compiled and gave the correct output.

code:

```
.cpu cortex-a7
.fpu neon-vfpv4
.syntax unified numa .req r4 numb .req r5 remainder .req r6 gcd .req r7 temp .req r8 quotient .req 
r9
.data
vara: .word 0
varb: .word 0
.section .rodata
.align 2
prompta: .asciz "Enter first number (a): " 
promptb: .asciz "Enter second number (b): "
result: .asciz "The gcd of %d and %d is %d\n" 
intfmt: .asciz "%d"
badnum: .asciz "The number must be positiveln"
. text
.align 2
.global main
.type main, %function 
main:
    stmfd sp!, {r4-r8, lr}
    ldr r0, =prompta
    bl printf
    ldr r0, =intfmt 
    ldr r1, =vara 
    bl scanf
    ldr r0, =vara 
    ldr numa, [r0] 
    cmp numa, #0 
    ble error
    ldr r0, =promptb
    bl printf
    ldr r0, =intfmt
    ldr r1, =varb 
    bl scanf
    ldr r0, =varb 
    ldr numb, [r0] 
    cmp numb, #0 
    ble error
    cmp numa, numb 
    bge loop
    mov temp, numa 
temporary
    mov numa, numb 
    mov numb, temp
loop:
    udiv quotient, numa, numb
    mul temp, quotient, numb
    sub remainder, numa, temp



     cmp remainder, #0 @ if remainder is zero
     beq last @ print result
     mov numa, numb @ replace a by b
     mov numb, remainder @ replace b by remainder
     b loop @ repeat loop
error:
     ldr r0, =badnum @ load address of error string
     bl printf @ print the error
     b terminate @ terminate program
last:
    mov gcd, numb
    ldr r0, =result @ load result string address
     ldr r1, =vara @ load variable a address
     ldr r1, [r1] @ load first number
     ldr r2, =varb @ load variable b address
     ldr r2, [r2] @ load second number
     mov r3, gcd @ load gcd result
     bl printf @ print the result string
     
terminate:
    mov r0, 0 @ return 0
    ldmfd sp!, {r4-r8, pc}
```

Errors:

```
Assembler messages:
:23: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.'
:50: Error: bad instruction `temporary'
```

Comment: Which line is line 23?

Comment: @Mary McBeth: As you are a new user, I would suggest reading this article: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like:

- You are using ". text" instead of ".text",
- You are missing a ":" after "temporary".

I was able to assemble a slightly modified version of your code:

```
.cpu cortex-a7
.fpu neon-vfpv4
.syntax unified
 numa .req r4
 numb .req r5
 remainder .req r6
 gcd .req r7
temp .req r8
quotient .req r9
.data
vara: .word 0
varb: .word 0
.section .rodata
.align 2
prompta: .asciz "Enter first number (a): " 
promptb: .asciz "Enter second number (b): "
result: .asciz "The gcd of %d and %d is %d\n" 
intfmt: .asciz "%d"
badnum: .asciz "The number must be positiveln"
.text
.align 2
.global main
.type main, %function 
main:
    stmfd sp!, {r4-r8, lr}
    ldr r0, =prompta
    bl printf
    ldr r0, =intfmt 
    ldr r1, =vara 
    bl scanf
    ldr r0, =vara 
    ldr numa, [r0] 
    cmp numa, #0 
    ble error
    ldr r0, =promptb
    bl printf
    ldr r0, =intfmt
    ldr r1, =varb 
    bl scanf
    ldr r0, =varb 
    ldr numb, [r0] 
    cmp numb, #0 
    ble error
    cmp numa, numb 
    bge loop
    mov temp, numa 
temporary:
    mov numa, numb 
    mov numb, temp
loop:
    udiv quotient, numa, numb
    mul temp, quotient, numb
    sub remainder, numa, temp



     cmp remainder, #0 @ if remainder is zero
     beq last @ print result
     mov numa, numb @ replace a by b
     mov numb, remainder @ replace b by remainder
     b loop @ repeat loop
error:
     ldr r0, =badnum @ load address of error string
     bl printf @ print the error
     b terminate @ terminate program
last:
    mov gcd, numb
    ldr r0, =result @ load result string address
     ldr r1, =vara @ load variable a address
     ldr r1, [r1] @ load first number
     ldr r2, =varb @ load variable b address
     ldr r2, [r2] @ load second number
     mov r3, gcd @ load gcd result
     bl printf @ print the result string
     
terminate:
    mov r0, 0 @ return 0
    ldmfd sp!, {r4-r8, pc}
```